# How to change other items in a Android ListView when one item is show

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, scrollview

How to change other items in a Android ListView when one item is show?

I want to change something, if the item appears on the screen in the listview

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the condition for the visible item to lead to a change go the others? What sort of change do you expect if that condition is true?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.